# Tablock hint triggers deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, deadlock, bulk-insert

I was inserting two data sets, using minimal logging, into an empty heap table using via two Execute SQL Tasks running in parallel and with SQL of the following form.

```
INSERT INTO Table (TABLOCK) SELECT FROM ...
```

After the job hangs a bit, one of the SQL tasks became a deadlock victim. Below is XML output of the deadlock graph.

Can someone explain what was happening under the hood?

```
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1586156746" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="dbo.TargetTable" id="lock7374a00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="1586156746">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process9609dc8" mode="Sch-S"/>
     <owner id="process9609dc8" mode="IX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process5e13048" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1586156746" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="dbo.TargetTable" id="lock7374a00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="1586156746">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process5e13048" mode="Sch-S"/>
     <owner id="process5e13048" mode="IX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process9609dc8" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
```

Things get a lot trickier because I found that for most cases the two Execute SQL Tasks can run in parallel successfully. Try below:

```
Create table dbo.TablockInsert (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int)

--then issue the script in two Execute Sql Task in parallel you won't fail:
insert into dbo.TablockInsert(TABLOCK) SELECT 1, 1, 1
```

Since the only difference is the SELECT... FROM... statement, looks like the SELECT... FROM... statement can have an impact on the lock mode here?

Comment: You could specify TABLOCKX instead of TABLOCK to prevent the deadlock.  Although that would also serialize access to the table, you would still get minimal logging.

Answer (score 8):

The [Data Loading Performance Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx) was written for SQL Server 2008 but as far as I can tell Microsoft hasn't made any improvements in this area for heaps. Here's a quote for your loading scenario:

> **Bulk Loading an Empty, Nonpartitioned Table**
>
> Loading data into a nonpartitioned table, while a simple operation,
>   can be optimized in several ways.
>
> ...
>
> Multiple, concurrent insert operations for heaps are possible only
>   when the chosen bulk method issues bulk update (BU) locks on the
>   table. Two bulk update (BU) locks are compatible, and hence two bulk
>   operations can run at the same time.
>
> In this scenario, both **INSERT … SELECT** and SELECT INTO have a
>   drawback. Both of these operations take an exclusive (X), table level
>   lock on the destination. This means that only one bulk load operation
>   can run at a given time, limiting scalability. However, BCP, BULK
>   INSERT, and Integration Services are all capable of taking bulk update
>   (BU) locks – if you specify the TABLOCK hint.

The important part is that you don't get a BU lock with `INSERT ... SELECT`. You'll always get an exclusive lock on the table, so only one `INSERT` can run at a time.

In the comments you said that you'll insert 100k rows or less and that other processes won't be running on the tables during the inserts. When sending two INSERT queries to the database I would expect one of three things to happen:

1. One insert runs first and blocks the other insert. The second insert waits until the first insert is done.
2. One insert finishes before the second insert starts. There is no explicit blocking but they aren't run concurrently.
3. You get a deadlock and only one insert completes successfully.

In all cases you either benefit or aren't hurt by adding a `TABLOCKX` hint to the query, so that is my recommendation of working around the deadlock. If you want to know why the deadlock sometimes happens you'll need to look to another answer for that.

For in a different scenario in which you really need parallel insert, two ways of working around the BU issue are to partition your heap and to have each session insert into a separate partition or to load your data through BCP, BULK INSERT, or Integration Services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the situation I encountered deadlock is the only case I have by now. For most cases when you issue INSERT INTO WITH (TABLOCK) SELECT FROM in parallel the job won't fail. BTW, I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I have added an successful example in my question.

Comment: @tec in the cases it doesn't fail presumably they actually end up running serially. Maybe you only hit the issue when there is a certain start up time eg for plan compilation.

Comment: @MartinSmith The query where I encountered the issue on the project is much more complex than the SELECT 1 example, which requires more compilation overhead but it is just reading from couple of tables. I am trying to reproduce this type of deadlock by more complex queries.

Comment: @TecKnowNothing About how many rows do you insert? How many times per day does the process run? Do other queries SELECT from the table while data is loaded?

Comment: @JoeObbish 1. I do not think # of rows is issue here, we only have 4000 - 70000 for each of the query and but they are highly aggregated data for cube use. 2. It's still under testing stage, supposed to run once per day. 3.Nothing else is reading from the target table.

Answer (score 4):

You are inserting into `dbo.TargetTable` from two sessions and both using `TABLOCK` hint.Both  `process9609dc8` and `process5e13048` process holding `Sch-S` and `IX` locks which are compatible with each other so both process can hold at the same time. But both wants to convert `IX` lock to `Exclusive X` type. `X` locks are not compatible with each other. Therefore, SQL server chose one of the session as deadlock victim instead of waiting infinitely for each other.

[Basic deadlocking information.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Lock Compatibility (Database Engine) chart.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Detecting and Ending Deadlocks.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx)